# Permission to change other users using Laravel Sanctum

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, roles, laravel-sanctum

In my Laravel application I use the package [Spatie](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/introduction) for roles and [Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum) for authorization.

During authorization, I create an access token using Sanctum, passing to the `abilities` parameter an array of roles created by Spatie during registration:

```
$user->createToken($user->name, [
    $user->getRoleNames()->toArray()
])->plainTextToken;
```

By default, users can have only two roles: `user` or `admin`.

When trying to update the information of another user (not the one to whom the access token was issued) I get an `AuthenticationException` exception even at the route level, before reaching the controllers.

My routes look like this:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    Route::apiResource('users', UserController::class);
});
```

Where and how can (should) permissions be properly configured so that users with the `user` role have access only to receiving information and editing themselves, and users with the `admin` role also have access to editing all users?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

I got recognized for my `abilities`, I had an influential person, basically:

```
$user->createToken(
    $user->name,
    // here will be ["user"] or ["admin"]
    $user->getRoleNames()->toArray()
)->plainTextToken;
```

In the update method, I added a check for the presence of an administrator role if the ID of the user being updated differs from the user who is authorized:

```
if (!$updateRequest->user()->id != $id &&
    !$updateRequest->user()->tokenCan('admin')
) {
    throw new AuthenticationException();
}
```